# How to send ERC20 Token?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, erc-20

I try to send Token based on Erc20.

and I can send Ether and something function 
but i dont know how to use transfer function in javascript like that.

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

i did 
first.

```
const TokenInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(mhToken.abi, '0xC632ecfBBcee37b8061E59fcA11d9cB80DE08612')
this.setState({ web3: web3 , MhTokenInstance:MhTokenInstance})
```

second.

using web3 instance i want to send custom token.
plz help me how to use transfer function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps.
Create a `web3` Instance

```
var web3 = new Web3(NODE)
```

Create a Token Instance

```
Const TokenInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(TokenABI, TokenAddress)
```

Sending Transcation

```
TokenInstance.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.then((receipt) => {
console.log(receipt)
    });
```

Which in your case will be

```
TokenInstance.methods.transfer(address, amount).send({from: senderAddress}.then(receipt => {
console.log(receipt)
})
```

Or can use

```
TokenInstance.methods.transfer(address, amount).send({from: senderAddress})
.on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
    ...
})
.on('receipt', (receipt) => {
    ...
})
.on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
    ...
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks bro!! you are my savior!!

Comment: If you find this answer to satisfy your question. Then please mark this question as correct and up vote so that other can find it easily