# ERC20 Token support for metamask website payment

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ether, erc-20, metamask

I have the following code working in my site to accept ethereum payments in my website via metamask....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button class="pay-button">Pay</button>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
          await ethereum.enable();
          initPayButton()
        } catch (err) {
          $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        initPayButton()
      } else {
        $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
      }
    })
    const initPayButton = () => {
      $('.pay-button').click(() => {
        // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
        const paymentAddress = '0x192c96bfee59158441f26101b2db1af3b07feb40'
        const amountEth = 1
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: paymentAddress,
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
          if  (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('Payment failed')
          } else {
            console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
            $('#status').html('Payment successful')
          }
        })
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Now I would like to know what do I have to modify in order to accept any erc20 token payment via metamask in my site

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Probably the same issue like how to send ERC20: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69684/how-to-send-erc20-token. You can get `encodedABI` of `transfer` function, and call `sendTransaction`. Remember to set the `data` key. All smart transaction should go this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. 
I saw in my contract that the function transfer(addres, value) is available. 
You must use this function. 
Hope it helps!